# Using Ubuntu-installed pc for commercial purpose

Tags: canonical, legal, commercial

My computer has Ubuntu Desktop installed and I want to do graphics designing and web development for clients. That means I will use my computer for commercial gain. **Does this violate any Ubuntu policies?**

Especially I did not understand the mentioned paragraph in the given link:

> [7. Use of Canonical IP by the Ubuntu community](https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy)
>
> Ubuntu is built by Canonical and the Ubuntu community. We share access rights owned by Canonical with the Ubuntu community for the purposes of discussion, development and advocacy. We recognise that most of the open source discussion and development areas are for non-commercial purposes and we therefore allow the use of Canonical IP in this context, as long as there is no commercial use and that the Canonical IP is used in accordance with this IPRights Policy.

Comment: Short answer: **No, it does not violate any policy**.

Comment: @M.Becerra Why not? Unless I misunderstood, he is doing graphic and web design, which means he won't be modifying and redistributing software. To my understanding, if I code a simple website in a text editor and sell it, I'm not breaking any rules. He will be selling his own work, not the software he used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**, this does not refer to how you use Ubuntu, but rather how you distribute it. You can use your machine in any way you like basically as long as you don't start selling Ubuntu because it's not your IP (Intellectual Property).

That's all that this refers to, it's nothing for you to worry about, you can use your machine for commercial gain as long as you don't try to sell Ubuntu.

(To be precise the non-commercial clause you cite refers to the trademarks of and surrounding Ubuntu and its manufacturer Canonical. Since Ubuntu is distributed only with free open-source software, you're welcome to take Ubuntu, remove all references to its name and redistribute its software however you like – in accordance with their licenses – including for monetary gain).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the meaing of "ip" in this context

Comment: @Paranoid Panda, there is another portion of text in the same link which says:

**Ubuntu is freely available to all users for personal, or in the case of organisations, internal use.**

What does it mean by personal use? In case of other open source softwares such as LibreOffice, GIMP, etc, they clearly mention in their website that I can use their software for commercial purpose. However, the Ubuntu terms of use are slightly difficult to understand.

Comment: @Maroof: Personal would include your graphic design work. Just don't read too much into this license agreement, it's legal speak, they basically just mean that you can use it in any way you like as long as your respect that it is their IP and don't try to make money off it in that way. But you can use your machine to make money, as long as it's not specifically the machine that makes you in the money because of it being Ubuntu. So to clarify that, they don't want you to rent out Ubuntu and make people pay you money to use it publicly.